# A specific question related to the Brouwer degree

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded, plus the relative open $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ of $\Omega$. Taking functions $f \in C^1(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ and $g \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ such what
$$|f - g|_{\max} = \max_{x \in \overline{\Omega}} |f(x) - g(x)| < \mbox{dist}(y,f(\partial\Omega)),$$
where $f^{-1}(y) \neq \emptyset$ and $y \not\in f(\overline{\Omega} \setminus (\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2))$. How can you conclude that $y \not\in g(\overline{\Omega} \setminus (\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2))$ also occurs?

Comment: You can't as stated. It is clear that there is more information that you've not bothered to reproduce here (otherwise what would be the point of having two $\Omega_i$, when all you use is their union). Look to that other information to find out why the result holds. For a counter example; $$n=1\\ \Omega = (-1,1)\\ \Omega_1\cup\Omega_2 = (-1/2,1/2)\\ f(x) = 1-x^2\\ g(x) = 1-x^4\\ y = 0.8$$